# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to read bytes from Mixer (Stereo Mix)

Tags: java, javax.sound.sampled

I'm trying to read the audio bytes from a given Mixer, in this case, the Stereo Mix from a Windows system. The project consists of 2 parts. One sends the AudioFormat and Mixer ID to the second one via a Socket (the one that throws the exception) that opens the given line from the Mixer so it can read the audio bytes and send them to a third party software.

The code that performs this task is the following one...

```
        try {
        line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(info);
        line.open(format);

        int bytesRead, CHUNK_SIZE = 4096;
        byte[] data = new byte[line.getBufferSize() / 5];

        line.start();

        while (true) {
            bytesRead = line.read(data, 0, CHUNK_SIZE); // Exception thrown in here.
            stdout.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
            stdout.flush();
        }

    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        System.out.println("Line is unavailable.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the concrete error message is the following one...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 800
      at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectTDL.read(Unknown Source)
      at org.Main.main(Main.java:69)
```

This error is surprising me as the exact same code was tested months ago and worked flawlessly sending bytes through the stdout.

**UPDATE:** The index `800` range is for 8 bit AudioFormat, if I select a 16 bit one the out of range exception will say `1600`.

Comment: I looks like from your stack trace that the error is with the library you are using and not your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the infinite loop due to the `while(true)` section. You read infinitely the `line` object which is an array, which means that has a specific length. So after 800 loops you reach the bounds of the array and there is no other object to read. This is why you get that type of Exception.

The solution to this problem is to check for the array length inside your while loop condition.

Of course you can perform this job with Stream feature of Java 8.

Forgive me for the lack of code samples. I am writing this answer through my phone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's strange that it fails because of that as the official example from the Oracle website seems to work in a very similar way, just changing the `true` in the while condition by a boolean variable. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html, see the `Reading the Data from the TargetDataLine` part.

Comment: The official example uses the global variable `boolean stopped ` which in a certain condition changes its value to 'false`. In your case the condition of the while loop is always true, meaning an infinite loop.

Comment: But even with that condition the loop could just run "infinitely", like if there's a Start and Stop button but you just press Start and let it run all day long. This just crashes at the start, doesn't even iterate a first time.

Comment: No this is not right. The example read is not a completed implementation. The `stopped` variable indicates that the condition of the while loop will become false under certain circumstances. These circumstances are not defined by the example. It is your job to implement it.